# Static Files in Subfolder ClassPathResource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflux

I want to return static files:

1)

```
resource
  |_______static
             |________assets
                        |_________css
                                   |__________bootstrap.min.css
```

The below is my configuration

```
    @Bean
    fun staticRouter(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
        return RouterFunctions.resources("/**", ClassPathResource("static/**/"))
    }
```

When I access `localhost:8080/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`, I get `404 not found`
Did I write a wrong pattern?

2)
However, if I remove `assets`, it's working

```
resource
  |_______static
             |________css
                        |_________bootstrap.min.css
============================================================================
    @Bean
    fun staticRouter(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
        return RouterFunctions.resources("/**", ClassPathResource("static/"))
    }
============================================================================
localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.min.css, 200 OK
```

I added assets because this is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Bean
    fun staticRouter(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
        return RouterFunctions.resources("/{*filepaths}", ClassPathResource("static/**/"))
    }
```

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-mvc-url-matching#1-uri-variable-syntax-foo-using-a-handler-method